# Pre trained neural networks to recognize certain things

Tags: neural-network, image-classification, image-recognition, image

How do you approach the problem or is not classification? For example, I would like to recognize if a face has makeup. But, in order to do this, it would first need to be able to recognize if it is a face. Since a very small amount of pictures are faces, I can’t possibly feed the `no_face` category with everything else. Also, is it better to recognize if it a face first and then use a second neural network to recognize if it has makeup?

Are there pretrained models I can download for common things like faces, animals, etc.

PS: By facial recognition, I would like recognize whether it is a face or not, not who the face belongs to.

Comment: Face detection is a well studied problem.  There are off the shelf detectors made by google, amazon, Microsoft etc or you can take any number of pre-trained networks for this.  The output of this will produce bounding boxes around faces in your images.  The next step is to train a network to take these faces and discern whether or not make-up is present, for which you will have to fully train a new model as I'm not aware of the availability of this dataset.

Comment: There are off the shelf detectors made by google, amazon, Microsoft etc or you can take any number of pre-trained networks for this? Where?